# Python string,re.match,loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

OK guys I got like 4 example:
I love #hacker,
I just scored 27 points in the Picking Cards challenge on #Hacker,
I just signed up for summer cup @hacker,
interesting talk by hari, co-founder of hacker,

I need to find how many times the word "hacker" repeats.

```
import re
count = 0
res = re.match("hacker")
for res in example:
    count += 1
    return count
```

Here is my code "so far" since I don't know how should I figure out the solution for this exercise

Comment: What is the form of input ? are these strings passed as a list or you have to take input from the user for each ?

Comment: I got 4 lines of text just and the word I am searching "hacker" is a string

Comment: `text.lower().count('hacker')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `re.findall`:

```
my_string = """I love #hacker, I just scored 27 points in the Picking Cards challenge on #Hacker, I just signed up for summer cup @hacker, interesting talk by hari, co-founder of hacker,"""
>>> import re
>>> len(re.findall("hacker",my_string.lower()))
4
```

`re.findall` give you all matched substring in the string, and then len will give you how many of them are.

`str.lower()` is used to convert string to lowercase

instead of str.lower you can also use `re.IGNORECASE` FLAG:

```
>>> len(re.findall("hacker",my_string,re.IGNORECASE))
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string1="hello Hacker what are you doing hacker"
a=re.findall("hacker",string1.lower())
print (len(a))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
2
>>>
```

*re.findall* will find all of the strings that you write.
Edit: I added the *string1.lower()* too as mentioned by Rawing.

> Your codes are not working because *match()* find the first match
>   only. Not all of them.

Comment: What's `string1.split()` for? And this won't find capitalized occurences of `Hacker`.

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
the_string = """I love #hacker, I just scored 27 points in the Picking Cards challenge on #Hacker, I just signed up for summer cup @hacker, interesting talk by hari, co-founder of hacker,"""
num = the_string.lower().count("hacker")
```

Comment: The problem is the code returns 3 times hacker instead of 4 times

Comment: I just added a call to `the_string.lower()` before looking for matches that way caps dont get taken into account, @Rawing pointed this out above

Comment: Thx man! working perfect.But I got a question there is one time Hacker with upper how does the .lower count him?I don't understand can u explain me please

Comment: so `.lower()` converts the entire string to lowercase and then `.count('hacker')` looks through the string and counts how many times lowercase "hacker" appears in the now completely lowercase string

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `count()` function , after split your string so you dont need regex , if you want to match upper cases too you need to use `lower` function :

```
>>> l='this is a test and not a Test'
>>> map(lambda x: x.lower() ,l.split()).count('test')
2
>>> l='this is a test and not a rtest'
>>> map(lambda x: x.lower() ,l.split()).count('test')
1
```